# Is 1.2.3 a double data type

Tags: c#, parsing

I am using `Double.TryParse()` to find if the given string is a number or not. I do not know how `TryParse` works. But when I give an input like `54.34.23` it returns true. I am working on a MVC5 application in Visual Studio Express 2013.

So is `54.34.23` really a number or I have to do something else with the `TryParse` for it to return false when the above input is given.

Adding a bit more detail `1.2.3.4` also returns true.

[image: The result that is being displayed]

```
  if (!double.TryParse(setValue.Value, out val))
  {
  ModelState.AddModelError("Value", "Value can only be a number");
  return View(setValue);
  }
```

Comment: What are you using?  I just tested and that didn't parse for me in C# (which the question is tagged with.)

Comment: i will add the screenshot of the result and my code. give me a minute

Comment: some countries use "." instead of "," as a thousands separator. try the culture specific version https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/3s27fasw(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: @Ewan and some use `,`, but it isn't a 10^(3x) separator. The  [Indian numbering system](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Indian_numbering_system) has `1,00,00,000` as a valid number with separators.

Comment: @michaelT: but when a number is entered i do not want the user to enter the separators for places but only for decimals.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If your thread culture allows the "." thousands separator "54.34.23" will parse to 543423

```
[TestMethod]
    public void TestMethod1()
    {
        string n = "54.34.23";
        double d1;
        double d2;
        Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = new CultureInfo("de-DE");
        bool test = double.TryParse(n, out d1);

        Console.WriteLine("test : " + test);
        Console.WriteLine("d1 : " + d1);
    }
```

However!!! I'm not sure that this is your problem. I suggest you write a UNIT TEST for your code!! you may find something else is happening

Comment: I will try doing that. Thanks

Answer (score 5):

Have you considered actually testing `TryParse()` to see what result it gives you to be sure.  I just tested it here and the following code in `main()`...

```
double x;
Console.WriteLine("Parse: {0}", double.TryParse("54.34.23", out x).ToString());
Console.WriteLine("Value: {0}", x);
```

...which gives a result of...

```
Parse: False
Result: 0
```

Since I'm getting a different result to you, it seems we have (as Ewan pointed out in the comments) a localisation issue and to fix this you need to specify which rules you would like `TryParse()` to use via the localised `TryParse()` method (documented at [msdn.microsoft.com](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/3s27fasw(v=vs.110).aspx).)

This takes 4 parameters and allows you to specify how the parser works in regard to what facets are valid (negative numbers, decimal points, exponents etc.)

Comment: What is the parsed value that you get back?

Comment: you need the version with string localisation  https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/3s27fasw(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: The parsed Value i get for `1.2.3` is `123.0`

Comment: @Ewan - learn something new everyday, I knew about `.` and `,` but I'd have expected it to barf if the separator was in the wrong place.  Just tested and was surprised to find it didn't.  It actually makes sense but was unexpected.  I'll update this to include your feedback, unless you'd like to put in an answer?

Comment: I understand that i have to mention the separator in the style attribute in TryParse. As I am unable to find enough examples, cani i just add a `,` in the tryparse as the second argument?

Comment: OK. I should be adding `AllowDecimalPoints` . But what if I want to add `,` as my decimal separator. Maybe I am not understanding it the right way. Sorry.

Comment: My `TryParse()` doesnt allow the value `1,2,3`. But what can i do to not returning true when the string contains `.` as decimal separator.

Comment: Note that `TryParse` of `54.34.23` returns `false` for **any** culture (among `CultureInfo.GetCultures(CultureTypes.AllCultures)`). Although I used `NumberStyles.Float`, which may not be the default. With `NumberStyles.Any`, the parsing results in the number 543423 for 93 cultures.

Comment: @mainma: so are you with a point that 54.34.23 can never return true? But is is returning true in my case